# Piping the output of one child process as the input of another child process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, posix

I'm trying to run ls -l with sort 
so sort can be applied to ls -l
but when i run it it doesn't give the same output 
as ls -l | sort
I'm not sure why I understand piping,dupe,fork,close somewhat but still confused
on how to apply them to make this work

```
  int pipe1[2];
  // will hold the ids of our forks
  pid_t pid1;
  // will hold the ids of our forks
  pid_t pid2;

  pipe(pipe1);

  // call our child process
  pid1 = fork();

  if (pid1 == 0)
  {
    // dealocate the 1 of
    close(1);
    // duplicate the write end
    dup(pipe1[1]);
    // close the read end
    close(pipe1[0]);
    // close the write end
    close(pipe1[1]);

    printf("child1 executing ls \n");
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", 0, 0);
    perror("execl error");
  }
  else
  {
    wait(&pid1);

    pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == 0)
    {
      close(0);
      dup(pipe1[0]);
      close(pipe1[0]);
      close(pipe1[1]);

      printf("child2 executing sort \n");
      execl("/bin/sort", "sort",0, 0);
      perror("execl error");
    }
    else
    {
      wait(0); //wait for children
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `wait(&pid1);`  why?

Comment: not sure, is it not good?

Comment: if pid1 makes lots of output the buffer will fill and pid1 will never complete. eg try with `locate`  or `find /`instead of `ls`

Answer (score 0):

add below into else {  [here]  wait(0); }

```
close(pipe1[0]);
close(pipe1[1]) ;
```

Comment: added them on the inside the last else before the wait and still getting ing sort child2 executexecl error: No such file or directory

Comment: /usr/bin/sort. check path.

Comment: ok the sort is working but its not being applied from the "ls -l"

Comment: you can add parameters. execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", 0);